# Slow initial Request .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Sitting in front of the task to create a new small service, I am wondering if there is some best practice guidelines to ensure a fast response time (including the first 1-3 requests) for that service.

First of all I love to create services with .NET Core and the webapi template (.NET Core 6). But having created some of them I notices the delay for the initial request for the service is very slow and all subsequent request on other endpoints are slow as well.

I was wondering if there is something I can do to prevent this, is there some advice to achieve this without sending requests to all endpoints on service start?
The service is not running on AWS or another lambda service like host. The .NET Core services "feel" slow if you compare to fast starting other services written in e.g. Node. I know the real performance(latency, throughput, ...) is another beast and I am very satisfied with that.

I found the following articles but was not satisfied with the result and/or conclusion.

- https://andrewlock.net/reducing-latency-by-pre-building-singletons-in-asp-net-core/
- https://blog.markvincze.com/running-asp-net-core-in-auto-scaling-containers-warm-up/

Is there a better way to "warm" the service or reduce the impact of the initial request?

Comment: How 'slow' is 'slow'? Is it taking time in seconds? or minutes? Also, are you loading anything in memory when processing requests? Correct caching is a major implementation detail of most microservice architecture based solutions. Its difficult to say what needs to be done without knowing details of current implementation. Typically, I expect my service to be able to respond in less than 1 second - particularly initial response.

Comment: Also, what is your API returning to the user? Is it reading the entire table every time? Reason I am asking this is because I have seen that kind of implementation in enterprise environment. There is just no way you can improve on that kind of implementation, unless you are ready to compromise on quantity of data to be returned to the caller.

Comment: It mostly does not matter which endpoint is queried. Single entity is loaded on the request, Validation/Binding is used for the request Models, Authentication is checked.
Slow means ~1,5sec on first request maybe 300ms on second, all following requests will be under 50ms.

Comment: "Services" you register into your IoC are instantiated as they are needed/injected. This applies to `AddSingleton`, `AddScoped` and `AddTransient` registrations.

Are you implying the need to instantiate a `Singleton` service during app startup? Because it sounds like what you require.

Comment: The article you reference has good foundational understand to solving a problem, but is far too generic a solution. I would suggest a DRY'd up extension to your `IApplicationBuilder`. Something like `.InstantiateDependencies()` as an example. Then just throw all your `.GetService<T>()`'s where your dependencies need to be instantiated during build.